# ICEfaces MenuBar horizontal orientation doesn't work

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, icefaces

i am using iceFaces 2.0.2
here's what i did:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:pretty="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
        content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"></meta>
        <link href="./xmlhttp/css/xp/xp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>

<body>
    <ui:composition>


        <h1>
            <h:outputText value="my application" />
        </h1>

        <pretty:link mappingId="link">
                   some link
          </pretty:link>



             <ice:menuBar id="menuBar" orientation="Horizontal">
            <ice:menuItem value="menuItem"></ice:menuItem>
            <ice:menuItem value="menuItem2"></ice:menuItem>
          </ice:menuBar>


    </ui:composition>

</body>

</html>
```

above is a header file made with facelets, and the menu items appears vertically, please advise why the horizontal orientation doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Horizontal orientation is default, so you dont have to specify that explicitly.
- Also try defining that in lower case, if you must define that.
- Please make sure you have the correct CSS that is being used by it.

Answer (score 1):

it was my mistake by giving the menubar a **css class** that was affecting the positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You have to test your page on google chrome, the orientation will Work. I'm having the same issue with FireFox and IE, but not with google chrome. May be it's an icefaces bug.